# Parse Error! using wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' );' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE) in /htdocs/index.php on line 17
```

Here is the *index.php* code:

```
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */
define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

I know it's something simple, but I can't figure it out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You have a syntax error on this line:(Look at the opening and ending single quotes, they are look different)

```
   require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . ‘/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php' );
```

the correct one should be like this:

```
require(dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
```

hope this will help you.